# Is this an efficient way of listing all .mp3 files inside in a directory (including eventual subdirectories) in Python?

Tags: python, regex, path, mp3

Is this a good approach? Is there a more efficient way to do it (without having to trade code readability for efficiency) ?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if re.match(r'.*\.mp3', name):
            yield os.path.join(root, name) # returns the path of the .mp3 file
```

EDIT: Conclusion:

If you ignore recursion, the fastest way to do it is by using the `glob` module. If you want recursion, switching from `re.match()` to using slices makes it few milliseconds faster.

Comment: `from glob import glob; glob("thedir/*.mp3")`. This actually uses regexp under the hood.

Comment: @doukremt: this is *not* a recursive solution, as required by Deneb.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Even though this is not a recursive solution, I will run some benchmarks to see if it actually performs faster than `re.match`. (Of course, not in a directory containing subdirectories).

Comment: You should first think about which behavior you need, then think about speed.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Is it so hard to write a two line recursive function to make it work? Seriously...

Comment: @doukremt: You can actually implement the recursive function using the same `os.walk`...

Comment: @doukremt: `os.walk()` *is* for recursively walking a directory tree, so if that is the task, use it. Of course, feel free to re-invent the wheel, if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python-based recursive directory walker should definitely include `os.walk`, that is the right choice. However, I would check for the extension using `os.path.splitext()` instead of using regex. `return` is not what you want here I guess, it terminates the iteration when hitting the first mp3 file. Replace it with `yield`. This creates a generator function. Call it from the outside, and you can easily iterate through all mp3 files in your directory tree.

A working solution, `test.py`:

```
import os

def mp3gen():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in files:
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".mp3":
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)

for mp3file in mp3gen():
    print mp3file
```

Test:

```
$ mkdir testenv
$ cd testenv
$ mkdir subdir
$ touch test.mp3
$ touch subdir/test2.mp3
$ touch foo.mp4
$ python test.py
./test.mp3
./subdir/test2.mp3
```

By the way, whatever you do, it is unlikely that the performance of this iteration is the bottleneck in your workflow. If it is, I would actually use the `find` utility using `find . -name "*.mp3"`, and then pipe its output to your Python script, then read the items from stdin using `for line in sys.stdin`.

Comment: Is `yield` generally faster than `return` in Python?

Comment: It is *not* about speed, this is about behavior. Have you actually tried your code? `return` leaves the current function, the iteration is aborted at this point. You will never be able to list *all* mp3 files with your `return` there, just one.

Comment: You're right. I didn't try the code yet, I wrote it with the certainty that it will actually work (I had `print(some_func(os.path.join(root, name)))` in mind, but then I wrote `return ...`)

Comment: I added a working example, to clarify how to make use of the `yield` here. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your eloquence and dedication have certainly earned you my vote.

Comment: Thanks for the nice words, glad to help!

Comment: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):` curious to know what Dot(.) means here?

Comment: @user1586957 The `.` means the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: You can only use this method if Python version is **>= 3.5**

You *can* use `glob` module for this:

```
import glob
mp3_files = glob.iglob('**/*.mp3', recursive=True)

for mp3 in mp3_list:
    print(mp3)
```

You can use `glob.glob('**/*.mp3', recursive=True)` if you want a list instead of a generator.